# How to make anonymous class serializable and pass it to IntentService

Tags: java, android, serializable, anonymous

I am trying to make an android application run in background. So I create an IntentService and I have to pass one object to it. So I make that Object implements Parcelable. The Probelm is that this object contains another object containing handler. So I thought of making the inner object serializable in order to pass it will parcel. But I got this error.

> 07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tinygsn.gui.android/tinygsn.gui.android.ActivityListVSNew}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = tinygsn.controller.AndroidControllerListVSNew)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   ?07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = tinygsn.controller.AndroidControllerListVSNew)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at tinygsn.beans.VSensorConfig.writeToParcel(VSensorConfig.java:772)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6814)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startService(ActivityManagerNative.java:2655)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1322)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:390)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at tinygsn.model.vsensor.VirtualSensor.start(VirtualSensor.java:109)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at tinygsn.controller.AndroidControllerListVSNew.startActiveVS(AndroidControllerListVSNew.java:126)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at tinygsn.gui.android.ActivityListVSNew.setUpController(ActivityListVSNew.java:98)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at tinygsn.gui.android.ActivityListVSNew.onCreate(ActivityListVSNew.java:82)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   ... 11 more
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: tinygsn.gui.android.ActivityListVSNew$1
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
>   07-29 10:16:08.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29387):   ... 28 more

Here is some parts of code:

```
public class VSensorConfig implements Parcelable  {
    dest.writeSerializable(getController());

}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<VSensorConfig> CREATOR  = new Creator<VSensorConfig>() {

    public VSensorConfig createFromParcel(Parcel source) {


        return new VSensorConfig(source);
    }

    public VSensorConfig[] newArray(int size) {

        return new VSensorConfig[size];
    }

};
```

}

and here is my other class :

```
public class ActivityListVSNew extends SherlockActivity implements Serializable  {
public void setUpController() {
    handlerVS = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            vsList = (ArrayList<VirtualSensor>) msg.obj;
            renderLayout(vsList);
        };
    };

    controller = new AndroidControllerListVSNew(this);
    controller.setHandlerVS(handlerVS);
    controller.loadListVS();
    controller.startActiveVS();
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?
If there is not how can I pass this object to my service. I use putPracable method for sending data to IntentService.

Thanks

Comment: i dont understand the confusion. U can either define inside the main object implementing parcelable how to write/read to/from parcel the internal second object or u can make the second object implement parcelable as well. containing Handler or not is irrelevant

Comment: The problem is that Handler is not my defined class. So I can't make it serializable or parceble

Comment: u can extend handler but still the purpose of parcelable is to exchange data from one component to another component and in handler u typically just provide some functionality (calling some methods)

Comment: So I didn't get what are you suggesting?

Comment: within the writeToParcel() method of the object that implements parcelable provide the logic of writing the inner object. and in the parcelable constructor do the appropriate reading.if u can post a simplify version of the data that u need to pass i can give a more accurate answer

Comment: So the problem is that for writing the inner object I must be able to send handler through the parcel which I can't as handler is not parceble or serializable. And there are some other object that I prefer not to change them.